# .NET Localization Project Structure subfolders for each language

Tags: c#, localization, globalization, resource-files

I have created a new C# class library project which will contain the resource files for all translations. The examples I have seen have a flat structure with one giant resource file for each language like this:

- Messages.resx
- Messages.fr-FR.resx

But for this particular project it is preferred to split the resource files into logical groupings:

- SystemMessages.resx
- UserMessages.resx
- SystemMessages.fr-FR.resx
- UserMessages.fr-FR.resx

This will get messy when we add more resource files and more translations, so it would be more manageable to have sub-folders for each language e.g.

- en-GB\SystemMessages.resx
- en-GB\UserMessages.resx
- fr-FR\SystemMessages.fr-FR.resx
- fr-FR\UserMessages.fr-FR.resx

But doing this will add the language code to the namespace e.g. `Translations.en-GB.SystemMessages.MyString` and I assume because `en-GB` is now in the namespace that the resource manager will no longer be able to find the `fr-FR` translation.

How can I put the resources into sub-folders based on the language code?

Comment: Don't know why the downvote,it's not a bad question...

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your project looks like this:

[image]

You could use different ResourceManager depending on the Thread Culture.
With a small T4 template you can make it strongly typed(iterate the resource file and create a property for each string)

```
using ConsoleApplication6.Translations.French;
using System;
using System.Resources;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(SystemMessagesManager.GetString("Title"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

       public static class SystemMessagesManager
       {
           static ResourceManager rsManager;
           static SystemMessagesManager()
           {
               //Get the current manager based on the current Culture
              if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "fr-FR")
                   rsManager = SystemMessagesFrench.ResourceManager;
              else if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "el-GR")
                   rsManager = SystemMessagesGreek.ResourceManager;
              else
                   rsManager = SystemMessagesEnglish.ResourceManager;
           }
           public static string GetString(string Key)
           {
              return rsManager.GetString(Key) ?? SystemMessagesEnglish.ResourceManager.GetString(Key);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

About the T4 template,check this :
[How to use a resx resource file in a T4 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885354/how-to-use-a-resx-resource-file-in-a-t4-template)
Below you can see a sample code.
Let's say you have this in your project:
[image]

Using the following template you can auto generate the class:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>

<#@ assembly name="System" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>

<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System.Resources;
using System.Threading;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public static class SystemMessagesManager
    {       
        static ResourceManager rsManager;
        static SystemMessagesManager()
        {
               //Get the current manager based on the current Culture
              if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "fr-FR")
                    rsManager = SystemMessagesFrench.ResourceManager;
              else if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "el-GR")
                    rsManager = SystemMessagesGreek.ResourceManager;
              else
                    rsManager = SystemMessagesEnglish.ResourceManager;
         }
        private static string GetString(string Key)
        {
              return rsManager.GetString(Key) ?? SystemMessagesEnglish.ResourceManager.GetString(Key);
        }

        <# 
         XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();        
         xml.Load(Host.ResolvePath(@"ResourceStrings.resx"));

         foreach(string key in xml.SelectNodes("root/data").Cast<XmlNode>().Select(xn => xn.Attributes["name"].Value)){
         #>
public static string <#= key #> { get { return GetString("<#=key#>"); } }
        <# } #>                 
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising. I am not very familiar with T4, but are you saying that it would be used to update the `SystemMessagesManager` wrapper class? Would this be a manual or automatic process to update the class as new strings are added to the resource file?

Comment: @row1 Updated the answer with a t4 template.One small problem is that you have to open/save your template if you add a key in the resource file.There are plugins that auto-run T4 templates on build but I don' mind this